# Regex em um switch case

Tags: javascript, switch

## Sobre

Tenho um switch que cuida da ativação dos meus menus a partir do endereço deles no site.

```
        switch($location.path()){
                case '/perfil':
                    $scope.menuAtivo.perfil = 'active';
                    break;
                case '/perfil/editar/1':
                    $scope.menuAtivo.perfil = 'active';
                    break;
        }
```

## Problema

Quando ele acessa o '/perfil/editar/1' quero que ele pegue qualquer numero ali onde tem o '1' pois minha url é '/perfil/editar/:id', tentei utilizando regex mas nao tive muito sucesso. Alguém teria alguma ideia?

Answer (score 4):

`switch` em Javascript só funciona com constantes. Para testar contra padrões você teria que usar ifs mesmo, ainda mais porque é preciso ser explícito quanto à ordem em que os testes serão feitos..

```
var path = $location.path();
var m;
if((m = path.match(/^\/perfil\/$/)){
    //nesse caso nao precisa de regex pra falar a verdade
}else if((m = path.match(/^\/perfil\/editar\/(\d+)$/))){
    var id = m[1];
}
```

Lembre-se que pra usar regex vc precisa escapar as barras e usar `^` e `$` para garantir que você está testando contra a string inteira.

---

Dito isso, é bem possível que já tenha alguma funcionalidade pronta no Angular pra fazer esse roteamento de URLs. Minha resposta foi feita assumindo Javascript puro.